# Image field with url

Tags: 8, entities

I'm searching for a image field in Drupal 8 with support to add images using url input. So when users has an image on his disk he can upload it and if the user has a image somewhere online he can link to it.

Does someone know a module that add this functionality to the image field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a module that just did the job that I wanted.

The module is called [FileField Sources](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_sources)